# error not enough values inserting data in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, sql-insert

I have a DB for pancakes this is one of the tables I created.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE ingredient_purchase_list
(    
    date_ordered DATE PRIMARY KEY,
    quantity VARCHAR2(15),
    unit VARCHAR(15),
    unit_price NUMBER(4,2) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT ingredient_id_fk  
        FOREIGN KEY (ingredient_id) REFERENCES ingredient (ingredient_id)     
);
```

As you can see here are the inserts to the table but looks like something is wrong.
Can you tell me please what it means the following error?

```
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO ingredient_purchase_list VALUES ('2019-11-15', 10, 'lbs', 0.79);
INSERT INTO ingredient_purchase_list VALUES ('2019-11-10', 4, 'lbs', 6.52);
INSERT INTO ingredient_purchase_list VALUES ('2019-11-15', 8, 'bags', 2.49);
INSERT INTO ingredient_purchase_list VALUES ('2019-12-01', 5, 'lbs', 4.25);
INSERT INTO ingredient_purchase_list VALUES ('2019-10-31', 3, 'cartons', 4.50);
END
```

I have this error:

```
ORA-00947: not enough values
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190200", line 592
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190200", line 578

ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2057
```

What is the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should list all the columns and be consistent about the types.  Does this work?

```
INSERT INTO ingredient_purchase_list (date_ordered, quantity, unit, unit_price)
    VALUES (DATE '2019-11-15', '10', 'lbs', 0.79);
```

Answer (score 0):

The right format for 'INSERT INTO' is..

```
INSERT INTO table_name(column1, column2, ...)
VALUES ( data1, data2,...);
```

So,,

```
INSERT INTO ingredient_purchase_list(date_ordered, quantity, unit, unit_price) 
VALUES ('2019-11-15', 10, 'lbs', 0.79);
```